# How i can add a hyperlink in the name of my custom map? google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add a hyperlink in the name of my custom map. For example, just now I add a name of my map of this way:

```
var mapQAPType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
  getTileUrl: customGetTileURL,
  tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
  maxZoom: 5,
  minZoom: 2,
  name: "Cluster Visualization",
  tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256,256),
});
```

But I want to, this name like a hyperlink. 
How I can do this?
regards.

[Example image of the name of the map](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4lU76DlyNSHTUJoaUhEYkdNNTg/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
<![CDATA[ TEXT+URL  ]]>
```

Read up on https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata for further information.

Comment: thanks
I tried to use that, but that dont worked. How i need to use exactly that? something like?
name: <![CDATA[ TEXT + URL ]]>,